# Django invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'11 20:11:22'

Tags: python, django

I want to copy an object from one model to another and I'm this ValueError "invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'11 20:11:22'   "

MODEL:

```
class TempLog(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,)
    start_date  = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now=True)
    end_date    = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        user= self.user
        entry = TempLog.objects.filter(user=user)
        if entry.exists():
            TempLog.objects.filter(user=user).update(end_date=Now())
```

## All of these is fine, but if I do:

```
print(entry)
    #queryset = TempLog.objects.filter(user=user).values('start_date', 'end_date', 'user')
 
    #new_object = [PermanentLog(**values) for values in queryset]

    #PermanentLog.objects.create(new_object)
```

I need them in datetime format not in integer, how can I by pass this?

SOLUTION:

First, instead of just "import datetime", I changed to "from datetime import datetime".

Second, instead of using `auto_now=True` and `Now()`, I used;

```
start_date  = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.now)
TempLog.objects.filter(user=user).update(end_date=datetime.now())
```

And as per advice of [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) I also changed to `PermanentLog.objects.bulk_create(new_object)`.

It works! Thanks [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem)

Comment: `ParmanentLog` probably uses an `IntegerField`, can you share this model? Why does your `PermanentLog` contains an `IntegerField` for `start_date`/`end_date`?

Comment: Good to know you got it working. Please post the "solution" part of your question as an answer and then accept it (you are allowed to answer your own questions) to prevent this showing up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
First, instead of just `import datetime`, I changed to `from datetime import datetime`.

Second, instead of using `auto_now=True` and `Now()`, I changed to as below;

```
class TempLog(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,)
    start_date  = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    end_date    = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        user= self.user
        entry = TempLog.objects.filter(user=user)
        if entry.exists():
            TempLog.objects.filter(user=user).update(end_date=datetime.now())
            queryset = TempLog.objects.filter(user=user).values('start_date', 'end_date', 'user')
 
            new_objects = [PermanentLog(**values) for values in queryset]

            PermanentLog.objects.bulk_create(new_objects)
```